# Allow dropdown/select to expand outside popup in chrome extension

Tags: jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3, google-chrome-extension, popup, overlay

I am new to Chrome extension development and i'm having an issue about limitations / how to play around with popups.

I have multiples dropdowns (using bootstrap) and select menus (using jquery ui). I want to keep the popup size to a minimum (let's say 100px max). I have two problems:

1) When I use the dropdown, the popup size gets much larger, covering the website to make up for the dropdown size. If there's more than the page maximum height, there's a scrollbar on the dropdown.

2) The select menus doesn't make the popup bigger and aren't completely displayed to the user.

I would like them to display outside of the popup, keeping the height of the popup at 100px. Tried playing with z-index and position, no luck. By the way, using normal, system dropdown works well (it leaves the container without changing the popup size).

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <title>test</title>

        <script src="lib/jquery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/jquery/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

        <link href="lib/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
        <link href="lib/jquery/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    </head>

    <body>

        <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <a class="navbar-brand navbar-right" href="#">Extension &nbsp;</a>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Test</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a>Test</a></li><li><a>Test</a></li><li><a>Test</a></li><li><a>Test</a></li><li><a>Test</a></li><li><a>Test</a></li><li><a>Test</a></li>
                            <li><a>Test</a></li><li><a>Test</a></li><li><a>Test</a></li><li><a>Test</a></li><li><a>Test</a></li><li><a>Test</a></li><li><a>Test</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <section>
            <select class="form-control">
                <option>opt</option><option>opt</option><option>opt</option><option>opt</option><option>opt</option><option>opt</option><option>opt</option><option>opt</option><option>opt</option><option>opt</option><option>opt</option>
            </select>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is wrong with native <select>?

Comment: Well, the popup is just a small DOM window so all the usual content behavior restrictions apply. Plus a few more like the maximum size is 800*600px.

Comment: I want more control over the design of the dropdown, so no native select. I know that there is more restrictions, but is it possible for the dropdown t be displayed outside the 800*600px popup?

Comment: there are many libraries that can replace and customize the normal select. go that route. you will not succeed in keeping the popup small using lists.